# How to use ToggleButton in Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to use the ToggleButton in my Xaml Grid Layout with
`<ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>`
but get an Error

> The Type 'ToggleButton' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been build.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ToggleButton is an Android control and is not exposed as a Xamarin Forms control

Comment: Is there something equivalent for xamarin.forms I could use instead?

Comment: The closest would be the [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/switch).